# ng-animate not working in 1.3

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am getting the class `ng-animate` applied to the directive but I'm not getting:

`ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active` or `.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active`

I have angular and angular-animate 1.3 loaded. and am including `ngAnimate` in app.js

```
<div class="message animate-show {{message.type}}" ng-show="message">
    {{message.text}}
</div>
```

The transitions are not happening:

```
.message.animate-show {
    line-height:20px;
    opacity:1;
    padding:10px;

    &.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
    &.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
        -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
        transition:all linear 0.5s;
    }

    &.ng-hide {
        line-height:0;
        opacity:0;
        padding:0 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: ng-attribute was deprecated in version 1.2. It is no longer available.

Comment: Turns out my default `.message {}` css was messing it up.

Comment: Could you elaborate / add this as an answer?

Answer (score 8):

For a simple animation like fading in/out, you need the following CSS classes:

```
.my-animation {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;
    opacity: 1;
}

.my-animation.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:

If you have other transistion on the element that you don't want to get affected, use the following CSS definitions to only apply the transistions on the fading in/out:

```
.my-animation {
    opacity: 1;
}

.my-animation.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}

.my-animation.ng-hide-add,
.my-animation.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;
}
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/W3yC9/)**.

Comment: The demo is build with angular-1.2, the question is regarding angular-1.3. Do you have a working example for angular-1.3?

Comment: @JeffreyHammansson: I updated the demo. Nothing in the code has to change. I just updated the angular version to `1.3.0-rc.2` and it still works the same. Don't forget to upvote the answer if you find t useful :)

Answer (score 0):

ExpertSystem's answer above is correct. However, if you still cannot get animation to work in Angular then you need to ensure that the ngAnimate module is added to your app:

> The ngAnimate module provides support for CSS-based animations (keyframes and transitions) as well as JavaScript-based animations via callback hooks.

See Source:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

This can be done in your code that defines your AngularJS app as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```